# How can I assign unique IDs to DIVs generated from multidimensional array in Meteor/Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I need a unique id for each div on my page. Right now I was assigning it in the helper with Random.id(), but I just realized that the id changes on rerender (duh!).

How can I get a static unique id? I know I need a counter, but I don't know how to do it with Blaze.

Here is my html:

```
<template name="article">
    <article>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            {{#each paragraphs}}
                {{> paragraph }}
            {{/each}}
    </article>
</template>
<template name="paragraph">
    <div class="container paragraph">
        {{#each sentences}}
            {{>sentence}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <BR><BR>
</template>
<template name="sentence">
    <span>
        {{#each forward.words }}
            {{> word }}
        {{/each}}
    </span>
</template>
<template name="word">
    {{#with theWord}}
        <div id="{{divID}}" class="word nonPopped" data-wordID="{{_id}}">
            <p class="pinyin thinnerBottom text-muted score{{score}}">{{pinyins.[0].pīnyīn}}</p>
            <h3 class="thinnerTop ">
                <a style="color: black;" href="#">
                    {{#each characters}}
                        {{>character}}
                    {{/each}}
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>
    {{/with}}
</template>
<template name="character">
    {{#with theCharacter}}
        <span id="{{spanID}}" class="character thinnerTop">{{simplified}}</span>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: No, sorry, it isn't a collection. It is a document with references to collection._ids and some of them are repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what seems to be working:

```
Template.word.onCreated(function () {
    this.data.divID = Random.id(6)
})

Template.word.helpers({
theWord: function () {
    var theWord = Words.findOne({_id: this.wordID})
...
        if (!theWord.divID) {
            theWord.divID = this.divID
        }
        return theWord
    }
})
```

If upon further testing this doesn't work, I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're iterating over a collection then just use `id="{{_id}}`. The counter is `{{@index}}`

Comment: No, sorry, it isn't a collection. It is a document with references to collection's documents and some of them are repeated in the array.

Comment: Then use the counter.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Not at my computer right now, so I can't quote the error. Basically it didn't recognize {{@counter}} to mean anything. It probably didn't work because this is a multidimensional array. Not sure.

Comment: Sorry, @ index instead of @ counter, duh

Comment: ```Error: Unsupported directive: @index```